# How do I make an awaitable blocking till a condition is true? (without using while loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency

How do I make it so that I am stuck awaiting something if the value of it isn't true?
for example :

```py
await stuff() # Gets executed
await continueif(x, True) # This only returns when x is True
await morestuff() # Will get to this part when the above statement is executed, which only happens if the condition is true
...
```

without using while loop

So, ideally

```py
x = True
continueif(x, True)
```

Should immediately let us pass through
but,

```py
x = False
continueif(x, True)
```

Should never let us pass through until or unless the value of `x` becomes `True` sometime during the execution of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I've created something around your code sample to create something minimally run-able. I've used asyncio.Queue, however if your requirement is for a single event asyncio.Event may be a better choice.

It's worth keeping in mind that asyncio is not multi-processing, rather there is *one* event loop that shares a single thread while some IO (typically) is blocking.

```
import asyncio
from time import perf_counter

async def make_true(myx: asyncio.Queue):
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    await myx.put(False)
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    await myx.put('hi')
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    await myx.put(True)

async def stuff():
    print(f'{perf_counter()} doing stuff')

async def continueif(myx: asyncio.Queue, condition: bool):
    while True:
        msg = await myx.get()
        if msg == condition:
            print(f'{perf_counter()} {msg} is {condition}')
            break
        else:
            print(f'{perf_counter()} {msg} is not {condition}')

async def morestuff():
    print(f'{perf_counter()} doing more stuff')

async def main():
    x = asyncio.Queue()
    asyncio.create_task(make_true(x))
    await stuff()
    await continueif(x, True)
    await morestuff()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Output is:

```
249083.3551413 doing stuff
249084.3697383 False is not True
249085.3773555 hi is not True
249086.3854538 True is True
249086.385835 doing more stuff
```

By the way, the `while True` is only required to parse multiple messages from the asyncio.Queue. If `True` is the only message the `while True:` can be omitted.